# Kernel Density Estimator: Misunderstanding in Taylor Series and the bias of KDE

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Let's say the kernel density estimator is given by

$\hat f(x) = \frac{1}{nh_n} \sum_{i=1}^n K(\frac{X_i-x}{h_n})$, where $h_n \to 0$, $nh_n \to \infty$, $K$ a symmetric probability distribution function with finite variance, and $\int K^2 < \infty$, and the true pdf $f$ is such that $f''$ is bounded and continuous (And samples $X_1, \ldots X_n$ comes from $f$).

Now, let's say we want to find the bias of $\hat f(x)$ for each fixed $x$.

Each $K(\frac{X_i-x}{h_n})$ is i.i.d, so consider $E(\frac{1}{h_n} K(\frac{X_i-x}{h_n}) ) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{h_n} K(\frac{y-x}{h_n})f(y) dy$.

Let $u = \frac{y-x}{h_n}$, then $du = \frac{1}{h_n} dy$, $y = x+u h_n$ so we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(u) f(x+uh_n)$.

Now, $f'$ is exists and is continuous since $f''$ exists and is continuous.

So by the mean value theorem(since $f$ is continuous and differentiable too) for some $x_1 \in (x, x+uh_n)$, $f(x+uh_n) - f(x) = f'(x_1)(u h_n)$.

So write $\int K(u) (f(x) + f'(x_1)(u h_n) )du = f(x)$ since $\int K(u) du = 1$ and $\int u K(u) = 0$.

So this would imply $E(\hat f_n(x)) = f(x)$, but this is obviously wrong.

So where did I go wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: $x_1$ depends on $x$ and $u.$ The conclusion after "so write" does not follow.

Comment: @whuber but you can still take the integral like normal no?

Comment: How?  You haven't deduced enough information to evaluate it.

Comment: @whuber ah since $f'(x_1)$ is actually a function of $u$ so you can't just take it out of the integral I see.